# In which table do tag excerpts get stored?

Tags: discussion, tags, data-dump, revisions-list, tag-wiki-excerpt

Where do tag excerpts get stored? The tag-wiki is stored in the `posts` table--we know this. I imagine the `excerpt` column is stored in the `tags` table, but the data-dump does not reflect this, and if it is true it would raise another question.

This is of interest because of the way post history is tracked. Because the tag-wiki is treated as a post, it's history (in the `postHistory` table) can be referenced using the `postId` column. This may not seem important, but...

The excerpt history is also tracked. And since the `excerpt` does not live in the `posts` table, the `postId` can not be used as a reference. So how is it referenced?

Answer (score 3):

After digging around the data-dump, I found that excerpts are also stored in the `posts` table under `postTypeId` of `4`. This still does not explain how a `tag-wiki` can be referenced by the `tag` itself. There has to be a `tagId` column in the posts table that's not visible in the `data-dump`. Can anyone confirm or deny this?

Comment: I can confirm we have a TagWikiExcerptPostId and TagWikiPostId in our Tag table ... if that helps

Comment: @waffles, thank you very much. It's hard to remember some times that the data-dump does not represent the full picture.